# How do you fix the height and width of a winforms label to accept variable length text

Tags: winforms, controls, textbox, label

I have created a wizard form and each page of the form will display some help text.

I either need a

1.Label control where I can fix the height and width of the label so it doesn't grow to long but rather wraps the text inside my fixed width and height.

But a label doesn't have sizing handles and seems to automatically adjust to the content.

OR

2.A textbox control (where I can already set the height and width if I set multiline off) however the user should NOT be able to edit the textbox...in fact the textbox should not be able to recieve the focus at all. (like a label)

Can someone tell me how to do one or the other.

Seth B Spearman

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For Label, 
You should set label's Autosize property to false

For Textbox, set Enabled Property to false

Comment: Thanks...just what I was looking for. 
Seth

Answer (score 4):

Labels have an `AutoSize` property, which defaults to `true` - just set it to `false` in designer, and resize as needed.